# Efficient SELECT with complex WHERE condition - do I need to store a column with the calculated value?

Tags: sql, django, database-design, normalization, django-orm

Suppose I have a large table to store ranges of integers. I can do this with two fields:

```
start|end
  10 |210     (represents 10 to 210)
  5  |55      (represents 5 to 55)
```

(quick to select by `end` column), or:

```
start|length
  10 | 200     (represents 10 to 210)
  5  | 50      (represents 5 to 55)
```

(quick to select by `length` column).

What if sometimes I need to select by `end`, and sometimes by `length`, and both queries need  to be fast? I could store both:

```
start|length|end
  10 | 200  |210
  5  | 50   |55
```

But then this is not normalised and everyone has to remember to update both fields, and is just bad design.

I know I can select by `start + length` or `end - start` but for a very large table, isn't this extremely slow?

**How can I query by calculated values quickly without storing redundant data - or should I just store the extra column?**

Comment: Any particular engine?  Some support directly indexable computed columns.

Comment: Cosign Larry Lustig. In Oracle, you could create a virtual column and put an index on it.

Comment: @LarryLustig Postgres or MySQL. I'm using the Django ORM.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the database type you are using, you might want to use a trigger to calculate the derived field. That way, they can never get out of synch.

This means that the field (length) could be re-calculated every time start or end changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd store the length, but I'd make sure the calculation was done in my insert and update sprocs so that as long as everyone uses your sprocs there is no more overhead for them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately neither of your target databases support computed columns.  I would do the following:

1. First, determine whether you really have a performance problem.  It is true that `WHERE end - start = ?` will perform more slowly than `WHERE length = ?`, but you don't define what a "really big table" is in your application, nor what the required performance is.  No need to optimize away a problem that may not exist.
2. Determine whether you can support any latency in your searches.  If so, you can add the calculated column to the table but dedicate a separate task, running every five minutes, each hour, or whatever, to fill in the values.
3. In PostgreSQL you could consider a materialized view, <s>which I believe are supported at the engine level</s>. (See Catcall's comment, below).
4. Finally, if all else fails, consider using a trigger to maintain the calculated column.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't support materialized views in the engine. There are workarounds, all of them more or less satisfactory. Or all more or less unsatisfactory, depending partly on how you first learned about materialized views.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I will update my answer to refer readers to your comment.